# Not able to renew Mulesoft DLB certifcates using AWS Manager

Tags: amazon-web-services, certificate, mulesoft, private-key, public-key

We have a public certificate created for our mule application.
We used this command to download the certificate and chain

```
aws acm get-certificate --certificate-arn arn:aws:acm:region:account:certificate/12345678-1234-1234-1234-123456789012
```

we are getting certificate Public key using this but in mule we are seeing two keys public and private pem.
Can someone explain which private key to be used here ?
What are we doing  wrong? Appreciate any help...

We have created a public certificate in AWS certificate manager since that is what we were doing before.
So We only have public certs and it's chain, i can't find which private key to use in mule.

Answer (score 0):

The private key is created with the certificate, and together form a key pair. The certificate contains the public key. So the private key that you need is the one created in the key pair with the certificate.

The certificate doesn't contain confidential information. If the certificate is for public or internal usage depends on your needs and its signatures.

According to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47703275/721855) you can not export the private key from AWS Certificate Manager for public certificates but you could do it for private certificates.